# Oracle OCI array fetch of simple data types?

Tags: c++, c, database, oracle, oracle-call-interface

I cannot understand the Oracle documentation. :-(

Does anybody know how to fetch multiple rows of simple data from Oracle via OCI?

I currently use `OCIDefineByPos` to define single variables (I only need to do this for simple integers -- `SQLT_INT`/4-byte ints) and then fetch a single row at a time with `OCIStmtExecute`/`OCIStmtFetch2`.

This is OK for small amounts of data but it takes around .5ms per row, so when reading a few ten thousand rows this is too slow.

I just don't understand the documentation for `OCIBindArrayOfStruct`. How can I fetch a few thousand rows at a time?

Comment: I don't know the subject area at all, but it seems that this question was closed not for its substance but purely because (prior to being edited) it asked for code examples, and this was (given the particular wording) interpreted to mean *off-site* code examples, hence making the question a third-party resource request. That seems crazy to me, as I argue at http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275063/why-is-my-not-an-answer-flag-marked-helpful-but-not-acted-on#comment267078_275066, and in any case that (entirely superficial) choice of phrasing has been changed, so I'm voting to reopen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `OCIDefineArrayOfStruct` to support fetching arrays of records. You do this by passing the base of the array to `OCIDefineByPos`, and use `OCIDefineArrayOfStruct` to tell Oracle about the size of the records (skip size). I believe that you then call `OCIFetch` telling it to fetch the array size.

An alternative is to set the statement attribute, `OCI_ATTR_PREFETCH_ROWS`, before it is executed. This tells Oracle how many rows to fetch at a time, it defaults to 1. Using this approach, Oracle makes fewer round trips and buffers the rows for you.

`OCIBindArrayOfStruct` is used with DML statements. It works in a similar fashion to `OCIDefineArrayOfStruct` except that it works with bind variables.

You can find sample code on the Oracle website.

Comment: Thanks!  I'll give the OCI_PREFETCH_ROWS a try first -- I completely missed that.

Re sample code: That is my problem -- maybe my google foo isn't good enough but I cannot find examples and I get completely lost on Oracle's site without Google.

Comment: Note to future readers: The correct attribute name seems to be OCI_ATTR_PREFETCH_ROWS (OCI_PREFETCH_ROWS seems to be some global envirionment varable)

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at the sample code in $ORACLE_HOME/oci/samples (if you don't have them installed, then run the Oracle Installer and tell it to install sample code). There are several that use the bulk interfaces.

You may want to seriously consider using a library instead. I've coded Pro*C (hate it), straight OCI, and used 3rd party libraries. The last is the best, by a large margin. The OCI syntax is really hairy and has options you will probably never use. At the same time it is very, very rigid and will crash your code if you do things even slightly wrong.

If you're using C++ then I can recommend [OTL](http://otl.sourceforge.net/); I've done some serious performance testing and OTL is just as fast as hand coding for the general case (you can beat it by 5-10% if you know for certain that you have no NULLs in your data and thus do not need indicator arrays). Note -- do not try to comprehend the OTL code. It's pretty hideous. But it works really well.

There are also numerous C libraries out there that wrap OCI and make it more usable and less likely to bite you, but I haven't tested any of them.

If nothing else, do yourself a favor and write wrapper functions for the OCI code to make things easier. I did this in my high performance scenario and it drastically reduced the number of issues I had.

Comment: Thanks for an answer.
Yes, I did have a look at the samples a while ago and could not find anything I could understand (Oracle's insistance on dropping all vowels from names and hiding any code logic in a mass of error checking etc doesn't help).
Will need to look at wrapper libs again, I guess...

Comment: The sample code is really, really poor, global variables everywhere, etc. I would not recommend basing any real applications on it!